# jQuery slider and sortable used together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to combine jquery slider with jquery sortable and use them on the same html page. See [jsfiddle solution by ostapische here](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/Dwsaw/2/)

The slider (which I use for highlighting items on the list) operates smoothly when the page is first loaded, but as soon as any sorting is done on the list with sortable, the slider starts misbehaving and highlighting blocks of lines in one grab, missing items, etc.

```
function setAmount(value) {
    $("#amountDivId").html(value);
    var value10 = Math.floor(value / 10);
    if (value10 > 0) {
        $("#listUlId li:lt(" + value10 + ")").addClass("checked");
        $("#listUlId li:gt(" + (value10 - 1) + ")").removeClass("checked");
    } else {
        $("#listUlId li:eq(0)").removeClass("checked");
    }
}

$(function(){
    $("#sliderDivId").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 30,
        step: 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui){
            setAmount(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#listUlId").sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {
            setAmount($("#sliderDivId").slider("value"));
        }
    });
    $("#listUlId").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: u need to provide at least the little js code of slider and sortable,also your html is very weird, inside your table you have li's

Comment: could you just reinitialize the slider every time an item is sorted? I think the changing of item order is messing it up

Comment: I did wonder if there was some way to reinitialize the slider, like doing a page refresh without the actual refresh, but I am not sure how. Open to suggestions!

Comment: Hi john, yes I took out the lis to try divs, but it does not work any better, unfortunately, but already there are some good ideas to try here so I will see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: $( ".selector" ).slider( "destroy" ).slider( "enable" );

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you have a very strange html structure for your sortables. The `<li>` elements are removed from the surrounding `<div>s` on sorting and because you use ids in the slider code, this gets messed up. You should simplify your html by just using an `<ul>` with `<li>` in it for the sortables. You should leave out all the `<table>` and `<div>` stuff (this is invalid html by the way!).

Then, instead of doing

```
if (score>=1) {$("#td1").removeClass('cellgray').addClass('cellred'); $("#td2").removeClass('cellred').addClass('cellgray');}
```

in the slider code, you should iterate over the children of the sortable container (`<li>` dom elements) and activate/deactivate them depending on the slider value. So do not use the ids of the elements there, as they might have changed their position in the meantime!

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will investigate what you say and report back. I was using ul and li at first, then resorted to div later!! I will change it back and "iterate over the children of the sortable container", when I know what that means! :-)

Comment: That means that you should use an `.each()` or a simple `for` loop to iterate over the the child elements of the `<ul>`. This way, the current order is taken into account, instead of using the ids of the child elements, which would ignore the current order of them. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/Dwsaw/) code.

HTML

```
<div id="amountDivId">0</div>
<div id="sliderDivId" style="width: 100px;"></div>
<ul id="listUlId">
    <li id="listLiId_1">1</li>
    <li id="listLiId_2">2</li>
    <li id="listLiId_3">3</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.checked {
    color: red;
}
```

Javascript

```
function setAmount(event, ui) {
    $("#amountDivId").html(ui.value);
    var value10 = Math.floor(ui.value / 10);
    var i;
    for (i = 1; i <= value10; i++){
        $("#listLiId_" + i).addClass("checked");
    }
    for (i = value10 + 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        $("#listLiId_" + i).removeClass("checked");
    }
}
$(function(){
    $("#sliderDivId").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 30,
        step: 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: setAmount
    });
    $("#listUlId").sortable();
    $("#listUlId").disableSelection();
});
```

Hope this helps.

**UPD**

i see you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/Dwsaw/1/)

```
function setAmount(value) {
    $("#amountDivId").html(value);
    var value10 = Math.floor(value / 10);
    $("#listUlId li:lt(" + value10 + ")").addClass("checked");
    $("#listUlId li:gt(" + (value10 - 1) + ")").removeClass("checked");
}
$(function(){
    $("#sliderDivId").slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 30,
        step: 1,
        value: 0,
        slide: function(event, ui){
            setAmount(ui.value);
        }
    });
    $("#listUlId").sortable({
        update: function( event, ui ) {
            setAmount($("#sliderDivId").slider("value"));
        }
    });
    $("#listUlId").disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Nice fiddle, but I should have been clearer in what I said, sorry. The color-change (highlighting) needs to proceed from high to low, or low to high, and do it smoothly both before and AFTER re-sorting. So if the order was 1,2,3 (using your fiddle example) and the color changes 1,2,3 also. Then after a re-sort so the items are now in the 1,3,2 order, the color changes 1,3,2 also. So the re-sort should not change the way the color is applied by the slider, regardless of the order of the items. This is the tricky bit, at least for me.

Comment: @Poppy see **UPD** in the answer

Comment: ostapische, this is brilliant. I will work with this example. Thanks to all who posted and hopefully as my skills improve I may be able to contribute help to others here also.

Comment: ostapische's jsfiddle works, I added one small tweak: if (value10==0) {$("#listUlId li:eq(0)").removeClass("checked");} to remove the highlighting from the last item. thanks to all.

Comment: yeah you right, I forgot this. Create a new version on [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/Dwsaw/2/).